# creating an admin user using django

Tags: python, django, manage.py

I was creating an admin user account, when it got to create password my keys stopped working!!I even rebooted my system and started from top boom it happened again

tried to create password on django admin user account?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, see how do I ask a good question [ask]. Take our [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and see what is on-topic here.

Comment: I think the keys still were working, you only need press enter: it does not show the password for privacy concerns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The prompt for the password when you use the [**`createsuperuser`** command <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/django-admin/#createsuperuser) does **not** show the entered characters, for *privacy* and *security* concerns. Just like a password box in a browser does not show the password.

You thus enter the password and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> to enter the password.